# Flutterで、DropdownButtonのアイテムに自作のWidgetを使うには

Tags: flutter

現在Flutterの学習を進めております。学習の一環で、DoropdownButtonのアイテムに、IconやTextを含む自作したWidgetを使いたいと考え以下のコードを作成しました。実行したところ画面に描画はされるのですが、一度タップすると以下のエラーが発生してしまいアイテムの選択やその後の操作ができません。
（お恥ずかしながら、エラーメッセージを読んでも何を修正すればよいのか分からず。。。）

【エラーメッセージ】

```
The following assertion was thrown building Container(AlignmentDirectional.centerStart, constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=Infinity, 48.0<=h<=Infinity)):
'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 5067 pos 12: 'state._element == null': is not true.
```

DropMenuItemのchildに指定できるWidgetの複雑さに制限があったり、そもそもDropdownMenuItemにはTextしか指定できないなど制約があったりするのでしょうか？
DropdownButtonのアイテムに自作のWidgetを使用するにはどのように修正すればよいでしょうか。

【コード】

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
      MyApp()
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'DropdownButton Test',
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {

  State<MyHomePage> createState() {
    return _MyHomePageState();
  }
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  List<DropdownMenuItem> _itemArray = [];

  _MyHomePageState() {
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
      _itemArray.add(
          DropdownMenuItem(
            value: i,
            child: MyListItem(i),
          )
      );
    }
  }

  void onChangedDropdownList(dynamic value) {
    print('onChangedDropdownList value = ${value}');
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
            child: DropdownButton(
              value: 0,
              items: _itemArray,
              onChanged: onChangedDropdownList,
            )
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyListItem extends StatefulWidget {

  late _MyListItemState _myListItemState;
  int _testIndex;

  MyListItem(
      this._testIndex,
  ) {
    _myListItemState = _MyListItemState(this);
  }

  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _myListItemState;
  }
}

class _MyListItemState extends State<MyListItem> {

  MyListItem _myListItem;

  _MyListItemState(
      this._myListItem,
  ) {

  }

  void _setStateSample() {
    setState(() {

    });
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        color: Colors.yellow,
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Icon(Icons.person),
            Text('Test Index = ${_myListItem._testIndex}, '),
            Text('AAABBBCCC'),
          ],
        )
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> DropMenuItemのchildに指定できるWidgetの複雑さに制限があったり、そもそもDropdownMenuItemにはTextしか指定できないなど制約があったりするのでしょうか？

複雑だったり、大きかったりなどの理由で配置でエラーがでるかもしれないけど、今回のエラー原因は異なるようです。

直接的な原因は、MyListItemのcreateStateで作るべきStateを、コンストラクタで作った物を返してるところかな。
createStateでは毎回新規にStateを作らないと駄目なはずが、そうではないのでフレームワーク内で必要とするオブジェクトがなくなってエラーと認識されていたようです。

StatefulWidgetについてきちんと習得しなおしたほうが良いです。

一応、動く感じに修正したのが以下のコードです。
問題だと思い修正したところには、コメント入れておきますので参考にしてください。

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'DropdownButton Test',
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  State<MyHomePage> createState() {
    return _MyHomePageState();
  }
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<DropdownMenuItem> _itemArray = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    // コンストラクタの{}内で変数の初期化をするのは望ましくない
    // 初回だけ実行するコードはinitState内に置く
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
      _itemArray.add(DropdownMenuItem<int>(
        value: i,
        child: MyListItem(i),
      ));
    }
  }

  void onChangedDropdownList(dynamic value) {
    print('onChangedDropdownList value = ${value}');
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
            child: DropdownButton(
          value: 0,
          items: _itemArray,
          onChanged: onChangedDropdownList,
        )),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyListItem extends StatefulWidget {
  final int _testIndex;

  const MyListItem(
    this._testIndex,
  );

  // 以下の様に記述するのがマストになる
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _MyListItemState();
  }
}

class _MyListItemState extends State<MyListItem> {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        color: Colors.yellow,
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Icon(Icons.person),
            // StatefulWidget内の変数はwidget.変数名でアクセスできる
            Text('Test Index = ${widget._testIndex}, '),
            Text('AAABBBCCC'),
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: ta.fu様
ご回答いただき、誠にありがとうございます。

ご助言いただいた内容をもとに修正したところ、見事に自作のクラスをDropdownButton内に表示させることができました。

的確、明確なご指摘に修正後のコードまでご提示いただき、本当に心より感謝申し上げます。Statefulwidgetについてもおっしゃる通りで、まだまだ理解が浅いので今一度復習しようと思います。

この度は本当にありがとうございました。